# Is it possible to pause Transmission and shut down the computer?

Tags: shutdown, bittorrent, transmission

I am downloading a 3TB file through Transmission using 10 divided .torrent files, and it estimates that it will take around 10~20 days total.

However I have to leave my house for 3 days due to a family trip, and I am trying to turn off the machine during this period.

Is it possible to pause Transmission and shut down the computer, and resume it back later? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: why would you need to pause transmission when you shutdown? Just shut it down and if transmission is set to start up when you boot up it will resume downloading

Comment: All torrents can be resumed, that is one of the many advantages of said technology.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an ubuntu question.

And the short answer is **yes**. Of course, you can stop transmission and shutdown your computer.

Just resume the download later.